# Manipulate dataframe output in Excel sheets

Tags: python, excel, pandas, pandas.excelwriter

Morning,

I have a dataframe which I am splitting into multiple sheets based on the Trading Book in a specific column. Once exported to individual sheets I'd like to autofit the data, hide gridlines and centre align the data and freeze panes on a particular cell ($B$2). The export has been done but the formatting in Excel is not working, I'm stuck on the autofit:

```
dfTemp = {  'Trading_Book': ['A', 'A', 'A',
                 'B', 'B', 'B',
                 'C', 'C', 'C',
                 ],
        'Client': ['AA', 'AA', 'AA',
                 'BB', 'BB', 'BB',
                 'CC', 'CC', 'CC',
                 ],
      }
dfTemp = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dfTemp)
print(dfTemp)

# Export each Trading Books data to a separate sheet in Excel
excel_writer = pd.ExcelWriter('C:\EOM_ML_201901\outputs\Excel_Data.xlsx')
dfTemp.to_excel(excel_writer, sheet_name='Consolidated')
# Get Book List
Books = dfTemp['Trading_Book'].unique().tolist()
# For each book send to Excel sheet
for myname in Books:
    mydf = dfTemp.loc[dfTemp.Trading_Book == myname]
    mydf.to_excel(excel_writer, sheet_name=myname)
    # Autofil columns
    for column in mydf:
        column_length = max(mydf[column].astype(str).map(len).max(), len(column))
        col_idx = mydf.columns.get_loc(column)
        excel_writer.sheets[myname].set_column(col_idx, col_idx, column_length)
excel_writer.save()
```

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Thanks @Blimitless. Will check when back in office. 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Freeze panes can be done directly from pandas when you write to the file:

```
mydf.to_excel(excel_writer, sheet_name=myname, freeze_panes=(x,y))
```

replace (x,y) with the row and column you want to freeze at, per [documentation here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html).

Unfortunately, that same documentation does not show a way to hide gridlines directly from pandas. You can, however, call xlsxwriter as the engine to use to write with: `mydf.to_excel(excel_writer, sheet_name=myname, engine='xlsxwriter')`

Then you should be able to follow the [accepted answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16342893/removing-gridlines-from-excel-using-python-openpyxl) to hide the gridlines.

For aligning center, you can use these two commands from the xlsxwriter package, depending on if you want horizontal or vertical centering:

```
cell_format.set_align('center')
cell_format.set_align('vcenter')
```

[Documentation here](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/format.html) from xlsxwriter, use ctrl-f 'align' to skip to the parts you want.

Good luck!